# Operand order in where clause for joining tables

Tags: sql, join

Does the order at the where clause when joining tables matter? In other words, is `G.GuestNo = B.GuestNo` the same as `B.GuestNo = G.GuestNo`?

```
Select GuestNo, GuestName,
From Booking B, Guest G
Where B.GuestNo=G.GuestNo
```

Comment: ordering is no matter for inner join B.GuestNo=G.GuestNo Or  G.GuestNo=B.GuestNo

Comment: The dbms optimizer is supposed to chose the fastest join order.

Comment: Unrelated, but: stop using the ancient, outdated and fragile implicit joins in the `where` clause. Start using the explicit `JOIN` operator instead

Answer (score 0):

No, the order of the operands doesn't matter. You'll get the same results either way.

Answer (score 0):

No. Ordering does not matter. you can have in either way.